# Adding to DataGridView by column or cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to add unbound data to a DataGridView by column/cell rather than by the whole row so that the next empty cell in a column is filled similar to this in excel

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This is what I've been doing for each button click

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Button1.Text = Label1.Text
  Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Button1.Text, "", "")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Button2.Text = Label2.Text
  Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("", Button2.Text, "")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Button3.Text = Label3.Text
  Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("", "", Button3.Text)
End Sub
```

and then deleting the blank cells in excel

[image: Outcomes]

At the moment it results in three rows rather than one row 
Adding a new row each time one of the buttons is pressed

Edit:

What I was hoping for was to have a number of buttons associated with each column (Button 1 & 4 with column 1, 2 with 2 etc).

If the user pressed button 1 2 times and button 4 3 times it would fill column 1 5 times. Then when button 2 was pressed it would fill column 2 but start in row 1 rather than a new 6th row same for button 3.

So in the end it would be a row where all 3 columns are filled in the row rather than just one column with two blanks.

I did have it as labels that were added when a submit button was pressed but that meant that the buttons still had to be pressed in a sequence that filled column 1, 2 & 3 before they were submitted

[New Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kDWC.png)

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't know how you know when you need to add a new row, but did you try something like this to access specific cells: `Me.DataGridView1.Rows(YourRow).Cells(1).Value = Button1.Text`

Comment: The new row/column would be added with the button click. Your solution only changes the selected cell

Comment: I guess I'm still confused about what you are trying to do. If each button click is supposed to add a cell, then it seems your original code accomplishes that. If you want to add a single row to hold all three button values, then you can add a flag to see if a row has been added and if not add the blank row then populate it with the method I suggested above. If I missed your issue completely, then you might want to expand your question to include specific examples.

Comment: Hopefully the new edit makes sense

Comment: Each click make 1 new row, because each time you execute rows.add, it Will make a new row.

Comment: Only add a row when you a cell already has a value, otherwise, if the cell doesn't have a value, then give it one.

Comment: If you Will edit, you can do it as @dashier said or DataGridView1.item(column,row).value=yourvalue, but you must now which row for second and third click is the row added in first click

Comment: Much more clear, but still you need to indicate what dictates adding a row. What happens if the user clicks `Button1` twice? Do you update the existing row or add a new one? What happens after all three buttons are clicked? Do you add a row, or update? Regardless, it's a simple process to add a flag to track if any button has been pressed and only add a row when the flag is cleared.

Comment: Sorry, Its that there is more than one button that would fill column 1 which I now realise I left out of the original question. Im hoping the new edit is a bit more clearer as to what im looking for and not made things more confusing